# Why feature extraction of text don't return all possible feature names?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, pytorch, feature-extraction

Here is the snippet of code from the book 
[Natural Language Processing with PyTorch](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920063445.do):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import seaborn as sns

corpus = ['Time flies flies like an arrow.', 'Fruit flies like a banana.']
one_hot_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vocab = one_hot_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

The value of `vocab` :

```
vocab = ['an', 'arrow', 'banana', 'flies', 'fruit', 'like', 'time']
```

Why is not there an `'a'` among the extracted feature names? If it is excluded as too common word automatically, why "an" is not excluded for the same reasons? How to make `.get_feature_names()` filter other words as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very good question! Though this is not a `pytorch` question but a `sklearn` one =)

I encourage to first go through this https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk, esp. the "**Vectorization with sklearn**" section

---

## TL;DR

If we use the `CountVectorizer`,

```
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

sent1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog."
sent2 = "Mr brown jumps over the lazy fox."

with StringIO('\n'.join([sent1, sent2])) as fin:
    # Create the vectorizer
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    count_vect.fit_transform(fin)

# We can check the vocabulary in our vectorizer
# It's a dictionary where the words are the keys and 
# The values are the IDs given to each word. 
print(count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

[out]:

```
{'brown': 0,
 'dog': 1,
 'fox': 2,
 'jumps': 3,
 'lazy': 4,
 'mr': 5,
 'over': 6,
 'quick': 7,
 'the': 8}
```

**We didn't tell the vectorizer to remove punctuation and tokenize and lowercase, how did they do it?**

Also, the is in the vocabulary, it's a stopword, we want it gone... 
And jumps isn't stemmed or lemmatized!

If we look at the documentation of the CountVectorizer in sklearn, we see:

```
CountVectorizer(
    input=’content’, encoding=’utf-8’, 
    decode_error=’strict’, strip_accents=None, 
    lowercase=True, preprocessor=None, 
    tokenizer=None, stop_words=None, 
    token_pattern=’(?u)\b\w\w+\b’, ngram_range=(1, 1), 
    analyzer=’word’, max_df=1.0, min_df=1, 
    max_features=None, vocabulary=None, 
    binary=False, dtype=<class ‘numpy.int64’>)
```

And more specifically:

> **analyzer** : string, {‘word’, ‘char’, ‘char_wb’} or callable
>
> Whether the feature should be made of word or character n-grams.
>   Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams only from text inside word
>   boundaries; n-grams at the edges of words are padded with space. If a
>   callable is passed it is used to extract the sequence of features out
>   of the raw, unprocessed input.
>
> **preprocessor** : callable or None (default)
>
> Override the preprocessing (string transformation) stage while
>   preserving the tokenizing and n-grams generation steps.
>
> **tokenizer** : callable or None (default)
>
> Override the string tokenization step while preserving the
>   preprocessing and n-grams generation steps. Only applies if analyzer
>   == 'word'.
>
> **stop_words** : string {‘english’}, list, or None (default)
>
> If ‘english’, a built-in stop word list for English is used. If a
>   list, that list is assumed to contain stop words, all of which will be
>   removed from the resulting tokens. Only applies if analyzer == 'word'.
>   If None, no stop words will be used.
>
> **lowercase** : boolean, True by default
>
> Convert all characters to lowercase before tokenizing.

But in the case of the example from http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920063445.do, it's not exactly the stopwords causing the issue.

**If we explicitly use the English stopwords** from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/stop_words.py

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> one_hot_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

>>> one_hot_vectorizer.fit(corpus)
CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words='english',
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)

>>> one_hot_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['arrow', 'banana', 'flies', 'fruit', 'like', 'time']
```

**So what exactly is happening in the case where the `stop_words` argument is left as None?**

Lets try an experiment where I add some single character words to the input:

```
>>> corpus = ['Time flies flies like an arrow 1 2 3.', 'Fruit flies like a banana x y z.']

>>> one_hot_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

>>> one_hot_vectorizer.fit(corpus)
CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)
>>> one_hot_vectorizer.get_feature_names()                                         
['an', 'arrow', 'banana', 'flies', 'fruit', 'like', 'time']
```

They're all gone again!!!

Now if we dig into the docs, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L738

> **token_pattern** : string
>           Regular expression denoting what constitutes a "token", only used
>           if `analyzer == 'word'`. The default regexp select tokens of 2
>           or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored
>           and always treated as a token separator).

Ah ha, that's why all the single character tokens gets deleted!

The default pattern for `CountVectorizer` is `token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"`, to enable it to take single character, you can try:

```
>>> one_hot_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b")           
>>> one_hot_vectorizer.fit(corpus)
CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None,
        vocabulary=None)
>>> one_hot_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'an', 'arrow', 'banana', 'flies', 'fruit', 'like', 'time', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Thanks, Liling. Beautiful answer!